# using different connection for Password::remind in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Despite adding $connection variable in User model, laravel still uses the default connection.  how do I get it to use connection other than the default?

Comment: Can you share some code?  How are you configuring the User model?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```php
Config::set('database.default','newConnectionName');
```